# How to perform basic Excel arithmetic in Powershell?

Tags: excel, powershell

```
$excel_test = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$excel_test.visible =$true
$excel_test.DisplayAlerts =$true

$excel_test.Workbooks.Add("C:\Users\Lab-User\Documents\Test1.xlsx")

$strFormula =  "=((A1:O29/10000)-1)"

$excel_test.Worksheets.Item(2).Cells.Item(2,2).Formula() = $strFormula
```

Basically, I have a dummy Excel file. This file contains bunch of numbers. From each cell, I want to divide the number by 10000 and then subtract it by 1. I want the answer to be placed in Sheet2, column 2 and row 2 (B2 in Excel). I want the result of each cell to be placed in the second sheet offset by 1 row and 1 column.

Comment: so you want Sheet2.B2 to contain the resultant numbers from hundreds of cells? Do you want it comma separated? You need to be more clear in your problem. Are you getting an error? Do you want the sum of the numbers in the range that you specified to be devided by 10000, and then  subtract 1? Please clarify.

Comment: Suppose there is a number in Sheet 1-A1, (number is 20000) in excel. I want this number to be devided by 10,000 and then subtracted by 1. This result (which is 1) to be an output in the Sheet 2-B2 cell. Does that make sense?

Comment: It does, but is there only ever going to be 1 cell with a value? What if Sheet1.A1 = 20000 and Sheet1.A3 = 50000? Will that never happen? Do you put 1 in one cell, and 4 in another on sheet 2?

Comment: Yes, So you have got the idea. Because I don't have only one value in the spreadsheet, I have mutiple values. So all the values need to be divided and then subtracted by 1. For example, I have values in each cell from cell A1:O29 in Sheet 1. The result of the arithmetic needs to be in Sheet 2, from B2:P30

Comment: Ok, you didn't say that last part in your question. You want the result of each cell to be placed in the second sheet offset by 1 row and 1 column.

Comment: I think you need to work out how to do this in Excel first before tackling the additional complexity of driving this from PowerShell. I suggest you ask that question on our sister site http://superuser.com .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need a For loop so you can process each cell, and I would suggest setting a variable as the range A1:O29, and then another variable as the range B2:P30. Then ($RangeA.Cells.Item(1)/10000)-1 = $Range2.Cells.Item(1), so the For loop is easy. I'll use your code to start, then make a blank spreadsheet and generate some random data for testing (you can use your existing one), setup the ranges, and then loop through setting the values in Sheet2.

```
$excel_test = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$excel_test.visible =$true
$excel_test.DisplayAlerts =$true

$workbook = $excel_test.Workbooks.Add()

$Range1 = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1).range("A1:O29")
$Range2 = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(2).range("B2:P30")

#Generate random data in sheet 1
$range1.cells | %{$_.value2 = get-random -Minimum 10000 -Maximum 100000}

#Set associated item in Range2 to the calculated value from the source in Range1
For($i = 1;$i -le $Range1.Cells.count;$i++){
    $Range2.Cells.Item($i).value2 = ($Range1.Cells.Item($i).Value2/10000)-1
}
```

Rounding could be done if needed by enclosing the `($Range1.Cells.Item($i).Value2/10000)-1` in something like `[Math]::Round(<formula>)` or use `[Math]::Floor()` to always round down, or `[Math]::Ceiling()` to always round up.